# How to calculate timedelta pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key-value pairs of type timedelta in '%H:%M:%S'

i.e.

```
myDict = {'0:00:12': '0:40:10', '0:00:18': '0:04:58', '0:00:50': '0:02:35'}
```

What I want to be able to do is calculate the difference between the key and the value for each pair and save those those differences to a list

i.e. for first pair `'0:40:10' - '0:00:12'`

Calculate `'0:40:10' - '0:00:12'`

Which is `0:39:58`, then save that to myList, so that myList looks like:

```
myList = ['0:39:58', 'difference-for-pair-2', 'difference-for-pair-3' ... ]
```

I got as far as

```
FMT='%H:%M:%S'
for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
  print datetime.strptime(value, FMT) - datetime.strptime(key, FMT)
```

this prints the differences in times I want like:

```
0:02:05
0:02:57
0:00:31
...
```

Which is correct, but I can't figure out how to save these values to a list rather than just printing on screen

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you not have a date component?  Depending on use, it can be very dangerous to simply difference time, as the two points can be months apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the answers of @wim @user35269 and @RandyTek
Here is the final code. Note that converting the datetime object to string will give you the desired output, to save or print out later:

```
from datetime import datetime

myDict = {'0:00:12': '0:40:10', '0:00:18': '0:04:58', '0:00:50': '0:02:35'}
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
results = []
for key, value in myDict.iteritems():
    result = datetime.strptime(value, FMT) - datetime.strptime(key, FMT)
    results.append(str(result))

print results
```

Here is how it look:

```
['0:04:40', '0:39:58', '0:01:45']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[datetime.strptime(value, FMT) - datetime.strptime(key, FMT) for key, value in myDict.iteritems()]
```